# Работа с типами даных java

Tags: java

**Есть такое задание:**
Дано значение числа pi, которое равно 3,141592653 и значение числа Эйлера е, которое равно 2,7182818284 590452.
Создайте две переменные, присвойте им значения числа pi и числа е и выведите их на экран без потери точности.

Если с рі всё нормально *то как 2,7182818284 590452 поместить в тип double ????* 
Последний символ не влазит !!!!

Comment: А может просто использовать строки?

Comment: @ RussCoder, та я сам над этим задумывался....Но задание так поставлено, поетому я в замешательстве!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При выводе new BigDecimal(Math.E) значение получится даже точнее указанного.
А вообще, вероятнее всего, имелись в виду именно выводы Math.E и Math.PI.

Comment: а как можно изменить количество знаков после точки без округления  ????

Comment: @Vitaliy , честно говоря, не совсем понимаю, зачем оно вам надо: какое-то округление присутствует всегда, пусть иногда оно и неочевидно. Попробуйте, например, `new BigDecimal(Math.E).setScale(10, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN)`

Answer (score 4):

Используйте класс BigDecimal для работы с цифрами такой точности.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html